# REST route resource by user

Tags: rest, architecture, routes, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have many resources like product, bookings and etc. Need routes to get all resources by user.

For example:

```
{GET} /bookings/user
```

I think this is incorrect, because this route would return user resource. Or I am wrong?

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this is incorrect, because this route would return user resource. Or I am wrong?

It returns a representation of the resource identified by `/bookings/user`.  What resource is that?  It's up to the origin server.

[rest](/questions/tagged/rest) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your identifiers.  As far as REST is concerned, `/6414b60b-1ecb-4e28-8887-4bfe120810e7` is a perfectly satisfactory resource identifier.

If you want human readable identifiers, that's OK too.  [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.1) encourages that practice:

> A URI often has to be remembered by people, and it is easier for people to remember a URI when it consists of meaningful or familiar components.

You should also keep in mind that RFC 3986 distinguishes hierarchical and non-hierarchical signal in the URI

> The URI syntax is organized hierarchically, with components listed in order of decreasing significance from left to right. -- [section 1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.3)
>
> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component -- [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any) -- [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

In short, if you are describing information that is described in a hierarchy, then using path segments makes a lot of sense

> I don`t return users and user ids, need return all booking for authorized user.

That sounds like you are describing a spelling like `/my/bookings`.

A heuristic that may help in URI design is to consider the benefits of [relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2); much as with a file system, you can use dot-segments to navigate toward the root of the namespace.

```
`/my/bookings` + `../profile` --> `/my/profile`
```

There *are* reasons where you might not want to support [hackable URI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/01/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-hackable-urls/); so you'll want to think about that constraint, and its implications, carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one would use a query parameter for this:

```
GET /bookings?userId={userId}
```

That would return all the bookings for the given user id.

Comment: I don`t return users and user ids, need return all booking for authorized user.

Comment: @J.Doe I would expect the endpoint `/bookings` to provide bookings. The query parameter `?userId=` specifies a filter to apply to the bookings returned. In this case, the filter would only allow bookings by a specific user.